# Spring MVC @Valid Validation with custom HandlerMethodArgumentResolver

Tags: java, spring

I want to register a custom `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` that could handle the following `@Controller` handler method definition

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String createDomain(@Valid Domain domain, BindingResult errors, @RequestParam("countryId") Long countryId) {
```

I can register my resolver, which just creates a `Domain` object through request parameters, by overriding `addArgumentResolver()` from `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`. When Spring tries to resolve the `Domain` parameter, it goes through its list of `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` (there are a lot) and picks the first one that `supports()` it.

In the above example, although my resolver will get called and my `Domain` argument will get initialized, the `@Valid` annotation won't have been processed **and** the resolver for `BindingResult`, an `ErrorsMethodArgumentResolver` will fail because it requires a `@ModelAttribute`, `@RequestBody` or the `@RequestPart` argument in the handler method, which I don't have.

If I try to fix it by adding `@ModelAttribute`

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String createDomain(@Valid @ModelAttribute Domain domain, BindingResult errors, @RequestParam("countryId") Long countryId) {
```

a `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` implementation, `ModelAttributeMethodProcessor`, will get checked first with `supports()` and resolve the argument (with `@ModelAttribute` and `@Valid`) before my custom resolver. The `BindingResult` won't fail, but I won't have my custom creation behavior on the `Domain` instance.

I could just copy-paste the code for validation and adding to model that's in `ModelAttributeMethodProcessor`, but I was hoping there was an easier way to resolve my parameters and perform validation without adding an object to the model. Is there such a way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Nice description of the issue that you are facing.

I checked out the code that you have outlined and have come to the same conclusion that you have - there is no built-in way to have both a custom  `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` as well as `@Valid` related validation applied at the same time, the only choice is to do what the `ModelAttributeMethodProcessor` does which is to check if the parameter has a `@Valid` annotation and call the validation logic related code.

You can probably derive your `HandlerMethodResolverArgumentResolver` from `ModelAttributeMethodProcessor` and call `super.validateIfApplicable(..)` atleast this way the existing code is leveraged.

Answer (score 6):

It's may be too late, but your `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` gets `WebDataBinderFactory` object as last argument, then, to hook up the validation, simply add this to your resolver implementation:

```
Object resolvedObject = // your logic 
if(parameter.hasParameterAnnotation(Valid.class){
            binderFactory.createBinder(webRequest,resolvedObject,"resolvedObjectLogicalName").validate ();
}
```

Comment: Very very efficient. Thanks.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, as it works perfectly without having to derive from `HandlerMethodResolverArgumentResolver`.

Comment: @Alexander  I tried this, but it throws the java.lang.IllegalStateException i.e.."An Errors/BindingResult argument is expected to be immediately after the model attribute argument in the controller method signature".

Comment: Validation works but my controller doesn't throw an exception after errors in validation.

Comment: It's probably swallowed by exception handler...You can also debug this in IDE and see what happens with exception thrown by validator.Aslo,what your controller returns in case of exception?

Comment: I had to do this:
```
WebDataBinder binder = binderFactory.createBinder(webRequest, resolvedObject, "resolvedObjectLogicalName");
binder.validate();
BindingResult bindingResult = binder.getBindingResult();
if (bindingResult.getErrorCount() > 0) {
  throw new MethodArgumentNotValidException(parameter, bindingResult);
}
```