# Create own class that transforms HTTP request to object in Spring?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, httprequest

I would like to create own class that will transform HTTP request and initializes object from this HTTP request in my Spring MVC application. I can create object by defining parameters in method but I need to do mapping in my own way and do it manually.

How can I do it with my own implementation that will pass to Spring and it will use it seamlessly?

**Update1**

Solution that kindly provided `Bohuslav Burghardt` doesn't work:

> HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: An Errors/BindingResult argument is
>   expected to be declared immediately after the model attribute, the
>   @RequestBody or the @RequestPart arguments to which they apply: public
>   java.lang.String
>   cz.deriva.derivis.api.oauth2.provider.controllers.OAuthController.authorize(api.oauth2.provider.domain.AuthorizationRequest,org.springframework.ui.Model,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)

Maybe I should mention that I use own validator:

```
public class RequestValidator {

    public boolean supports(Class clazz) {
        return AuthorizationRequest.class.equals(clazz);
    }

    public void validate(Object obj, Errors e) {
        AuthorizationRequest request = (AuthorizationRequest) obj;
        if ("foobar".equals(request.getClientId())) {
            e.reject("clientId", "nomatch");
        }
    }

}
```

and declaration of my method in controller (please not there is needed a validation - `@Valid`):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/authorize", method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})
    public String authorize(
            @Valid AuthorizationRequest authorizationRequest,
            BindingResult result
    ) {

}
```

I have two configurations classes in my application.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableWebMvc
@PropertySource("classpath:/jdbc.properties")
public class ApplicationConfig {
}
```

and

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebappConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
        argumentResolvers.add(new AuthorizationRequestArgumentResolver());
    }

}
```

**What is wrong?**

**Update 2**

The problem is with param `BindingResult result`, when I remove it it works. But I need the result to process it when some errors occur.

Comment: The problem seems to be caused by the fact that you can't use `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` with `@Valid` annotation. See [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18091936/spring-mvc-valid-validation-with-custom-handlermethodargumentresolver) for more details. Unforunately I've never personally used it in this scenario. Maybe some information from that post will help. I will try to look into it and update my answer with a solution, if I find one that works.

Comment: Yes, probably, I have no idea why I cannot use `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver ` and `@Valid` at the same time. Diky.

Comment: What is a `authRequest` in your code? I assume to add this code to my `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` implementation?

Comment: Removed previous comment. See updated answer for workaround. The authRequest is supposed to be your authorization request (updated it from foo to reflect the changes in the question). Let me know if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your requirements correctly, you could implement custom [`HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/method/support/HandlerMethodArgumentResolver.html) for that purpose. See example below for implementation details:

---

**Model object**

```
public class AuthorizationRequestHolder {
    @Valid
    private AuthorizationRequest authorizationRequest;
    private BindingResult bindingResult;
    // Constructors, accessors omitted
}
```

**Resolver**

```
public class AuthorizationRequestMethodArgumentResolver implements HandlerMethodArgumentResolver {
    @Override
    public boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter parameter) {
        return AuthorizationRequestHolder.class.isAssignableFrom(parameter.getParameterType());
    }

    @Override
    public Object resolveArgument(MethodParameter parameter,
                                  ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer,
                                  NativeWebRequest webRequest,
                                  WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory) throws Exception {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) webRequest.getNativeRequest();
        // Map the authorization request
        AuthorizationRequest authRequest = mapFromServletRequest(request);
        AuthorizationRequestHolder authRequestHolder = new AuthorizationRequestHolder(authRequest);
        // Validate the request
        if (parameter.hasParameterAnnotation(Valid.class)) {
            WebDataBinder binder = binderFactory.createBinder(webRequest, authRequestHolder, parameter.getParameterName());
            binder.validate();
            authRequestHolder.setBindingResult(binder.getBindingResult());
        }
        return authRequestHolder;
    }
}
```

**Configuration**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebappConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
        argumentResolvers.add(new AuthorizationRequestMethodArgumentResolver());
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
@RequestMapping("/auth")
public void doSomething(@Valid AuthRequestHolder authRequestHolder) {
    if (authRequestHolder.getBindingResult().hasErrors()) {
        // Process errors
    }
    AuthorizationRequest authRequest = authRequestHolder.getAuthRequest();
    // Do something with the authorization request
}
```

**Edit**: Updated answer with workaround to non-supported usage of `@Valid` with `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` parameters.

Comment: What is `mapFromServletRequest(request)` in your Resolver class? That sounds like the key to solve this question.