# Spring REST how to validate request body in different ways?

Tags: java, spring, validation

With `@Valid` we can parse the request body and validate it with annotations like `@NotEmpty`, `@Size(min = 5)`. Is there a way to have multiples ways to validate the body? For example, on some endpoints, I would like to ignore some validators (`@NotNull` in my case).

My guess was to create a custom annotation like `@ValidUnlessNull`, but how can I implement its resolver without having to do the job of `@RequestBody` (I tried to implement a `Filter` and a `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can define custom validation groups and select any group with `@Validated` annotation.

1) Define empty interface, that will be used as validation group identifier:

```
public interface FirstValidateGroup{}
```

2) Bind validation annotation to specified interface (group):

```
public class Person{

    @NotBlank(groups = {FirstValidateGroup.class})
    private String firstName;
    @NotBlank
    private String lastName;

    //... getters and setters
}
```

Note, that you can bind multiple groups for one property.

3) Select group of validation with `@Validated` annotation:

```
public ResponseEntity<Person> add(@Validated({FirstValidateGroup.class}) 
                                  @RequestBody Person person){
   ...
}
```

Now, only `firstName` property will be validated. You can specify multiple groups in `@Validated` annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Validation group is your friend.  You just need to provide appropriate group per endpoint. 
See my comment here [Spring MVC @Valid Validation with custom HandlerMethodArgumentResolver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18091936/spring-mvc-valid-validation-with-custom-handlermethodargumentresolver/29123428#29123428) to invoke validation with group hint.